# Is there a way to add recoil to the player screen in A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I want to make the player look up just a little by using javascript to force the player's rotation upwards. Is there anyway to make this happen outside of the player actually looking up themselves? Im thinking the most likely manner would be using the .setAttribute() function and setting some sort of rotation, but ive messed around with it and cant find a way.

Answer (score 0):

If the target platform is VR, you can't directly control the camera position, as that always follows the headset movement.

What you can do is wrap the camera entity inside another entity (commonly we call this a "rig") and modify the position or rotation of that.

This is how we achieve effects like teleporting in VR, and could be used to achieve a recoil effect too.

Set the `rotation` attribute on the rig entity (possibly using `animation` component to smooth the movement).

Bear in mind that this kind of movement in VR can lead to motion sickness, so take care with how you use these effects.

Some example code:

```
<a-entity id="cameraRig" rotation="20 0 0">
  <a-entity camera look-controls position="0 1.6 0">
  </a-entity>
  <a-entity hand-controls="hand: left">
  </a-entity>
  <a-entity hand-controls="hand: right">
  </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```